# string append string_view unexpected result

Tags: c++, string-view

```
#include <iostream>
std::string_view return_string_view();
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string got;
  auto peeked = return_string_view();
  got += peeked;
  cout << got << endl;
  return 0;
}
string_view return_string_view()
{
  string const s = string().assign( 2, 'x' );
  auto sv = string_view( s.c_str() );
  return sv;
}
```

os version

```
Linux vm 5.19.0-45-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 7 09:08:58 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

gcc version

```
Linux vm 5.19.0-45-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 7 09:08:58 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

[debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r95a.png)
[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTvpL.png)

expected return "xx",but why return weird string?

Comment: A quote from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view#Notes): _"It is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that `std::string_view` does not outlive the pointed-to character array"_

Comment: *expected return "xx"*  Hmm, I expected undefined behavior.  And, unfortunately, no compiler warnings, and the sanitizers didn't trip either.

Comment: Treat `std::string_view` as you would pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`s` is destroyed at the end of the scope (when `return_string_view` returns) so the `std::string_view` returned by `return_string_view` is a view over a `std::string` that has stopped existing.

Keep in mind that a `string_view` doesn't own the memory it's a view over. It is typically implemented as a pointer and a length, but the actual data is owned by `s`.

Reading from the memory pointed out by the `string_view` makes the program have undefined behavior. The program could crash, or worse.

Comment: but why in the `main` fuction , `peeked.front() `return 'x' ?

Comment: @jurkDang It could return anything or crash since calling `peeked.front()` in `main` has _undefined behavior_. It's just like if you had `const char* foo() { std::string x = "Hello"; return x.c_str(); }` and then did `std::cout << foo();`. Same issue. The pointer is invalid after `x` has gone out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

when the `return_string_view` function returns the string dies and the pointer from `s.c_str()` doesn't point to what you expect anymore.

As @heap-underrun points out, it is noted on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view#Notes), it is your job to ensure that the pointed to array is still alive. Which it is not.